# jQuery Plugin Tutorial: test-alery won't display

Tags: jquery

I'm new to js and jQuery - following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9oKDHP8Q8s

... as far as I can tell, my code is identical to that visible at 4:13, and yet my alert doesn't show.
The only difference is the google library is a newer version. I've scoured the code for any typo, and can't  find one.

I'm using up-to-date versions of Firefox and Chrome (works in neither). Alerts prompts work in regular javascript.

Here's the html file:
http://www.filedropper.com/jqueryplugintut

If anyone can give me a clue what's wrong here, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Post the code here, do you expect us to watch the video or download files to help you ?

Comment: Did you install WAMP, XAMPP or another local server to test this on? And you should save your files as UTF8, the downloaded file is CP1252-

Comment: Just provided the video link as a reference point. 
Not running a local server - just notepad++ and a browser. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: Nope, that wont work with the jQuery link. It will work if you add a protocol like the answers below suggest, but you should really download a webserver to test this on, like WAMP if you're on windows, and then the links given in the Google CDN's will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

You've put the wrong 'src' on the jQuery library script. It needs http: before the two forward slashed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should really post the code with your question. You'll get more feedback if you do.

Comment: No it does'nt! At least not on a proper webserver!

Comment: The OP had originally begun the source with a forward slash, which would make the link relative. It needed to be an absolute path to the jQuery library.

Comment: Now I had to download the file, and the OP has copied the link from Google, and it starts with two slashes, which is a technique to make it protocol independent, and should work just fine (If the OP is using a proper server to test this).

Comment: @adeneo Well it doesn't work locally hosted. The link works without the slashes or with http: before but it doesn't work with just the two slashes before. Going back to the original issue, the problem turned out to be that the jQuery library wasn't loading for the OP, so whether or not you think you're right, I tested my answer which solved the problem.

Comment: It works just fine locally without the protocol, if you use a proper webserver, like WAMP etc.

Comment: Yes, the http: was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo As you can see from the OP comments, he isn't using a webserver like WAMP, and nor do thousands of other web developers. My answer is therefore the solution to this question. Whether or not a protocol-relative link should be used when the site is live on a server is a completely different matter.

Comment: That comment was posted half an hour after you answered, so that seems somewhat irrelevant, and ***all*** web developers who do this as a living use a webserver to test code, otherwise it's almost impossible to get stuff working, unless you're just writing the simplest of html ?

Comment: @coop: yes that was the answer.

Comment: @adeno: "amateur enthusiast" best describes me. (Probably overlooking a protocall calls me out on that!) I will note the topic of the advantages of local webservers. Thank you for your input.